# how to compute: $ \int_{\mathbb R^2}\int_D \left( \frac{1}{|y|^{2-a}}-\frac{1}{|x-y|^{2-a}}\right)dydx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

How to compute the following double integral:
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^2}\int_D \left( \frac{1}{|y|^{2-a}}-\frac{1}{|x-y|^{2-a}}\right)dydx$$

where $D:=\{ y\in\mathbb R^2: x_1y_1+x_2y_2=0\}$ and $a\in (0,1)$. Here $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

I have no idea to compute it even for some fix $a$. Can someone help me or suggest a way to do?

Comment: $D$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which means $\int_D$ of any function is zero. Or is $\int_D dy$ supposed to be a curve integral along a parameterization of $D$?

Comment: you're right. Here $\int_D f dy$ means the line integral. i.e $\int_D f dy:= \int_D f ds(y)$

Comment: For what $a$ does this even converge?

Comment: I do not know what range of a so that it converges. I only want to what ideas to compute it. Also, I want to know how to determine the integral converges or not?

Comment: It looks to me like it never converges, except of course when $a=2$.